# ¿Por qué no se reconoce la etiqueta php usando backsticks?

Tags: php, html, teclado

Dentro del body quiero utilizar la etiqueta de php con los backsticks. Utilizo el comando **Alt+96** pero no me reconoce luego la extensión del editor la etiqueta. Como si estuviera mal configurada. En qué le estoy errando?

```
   <body>
      `<?php

         <div class=`{@}`>
         </div>
      >`
   </body>
```

Comment: No acabo de verle el sentido a lo que estas escribiendo... porque quieres usar backsticks? y porque dentro del atributo **class=**?  Alli deberian ir solo comillas dobles o apostrofes, no backsticks que yo sepa, a menos que uses algun sistema de plantillas raro que desconozco y que los necesita

Comment: Te falta aclarar cuál es la salida de deseas o necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **backsticks** donde te apetezca, aunque yo no le veo el sentido.

Lo que no puedes hacer es reinventar el PHP :-)

Fíjate en los siguientes errores que tienes:

1. Abres el tag `<?php` pero no lo cierras bien.  Debes cerrarlo con `?>` y no con `>`.
2. Dentro del código *PHP* estás escribiendo **HTML** y eso va a darte error, pues lo escribes tal cual en lugar de usar `echo` o asignarlo a una variable **entrecomillandolo con apostrofes o comillas dobles**.

Tal como lo veo, lo que pretendes es esto:

```
<body>
      `<?php
echo '
         <div class=`{@}`>
         </div>';
     ?>`
   </body>
```

Eso debería funcionarte, aunque sigo sin entender porque usar **backsticks**, pero al menos eso no da error y te ofrece esta salida:

```
<body>
      `
         <div class=`{@}`>
         </div>`
   </body>
```

Comment: Por backsticks me refiero a esa comilla simple que te permite escribir etiquetas php luego. 
Si uso las comillas que mencionas al final, no hace falta incluir la etiqueta php?
Mi intención es crear un for que imprima tantos div (con su clase respectiva), como objetos haya en un json

Comment: Me falta contexto para contestar bien. No se si estas editando un archivo PHP (con extensión .php) o bien es una plantilla de algun tipo de algun framework que desconozco.  Si es un archivo PHP tan solo necesitas abrir `<?php` y cerrar el php `?>` sin ningun tipo de comillas para poner dentro de esos tags tu código PHP. Si es un framework con plantillas deberias especificar cual es.